How do I distribute these rows of edges evenly?
How can I distribute these rows of edges evenly? I can get it close by eyeballing it, but I want it to be mathematically precise. Using the recommended LoopTools > Space created unwanted, weird results.


Enable the built-in addon LoopTools via menu Edit > Preferences > Add-ons > LoopTools

Select the horizontal edge loops then RMB > LoopTools > Space

